# Auth guard[] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8 and I was trying to make a guard 'mobile'. I followed some tutorials online but I don't know why what seems to be working in those tutorials is not working at my end.
I searched on internet and all I could find was `php artisan config:clear` and it never worked for me.

this is code from my `auth.php` file:

```php
    <?php
    
    return [
    
    
        'defaults' => [
            'guard' => 'web',
            'passwords' => 'users',
        ],
    
       
    
        'guards' => [
            'web' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],
            'mobile'=> [
                'driver'=>'session',
                'provider'=>'technicians'
            ],
            'api' => [
                'driver' => 'sanctum',
                'provider' => 'users',
                'hash' => false,
            ]
        ],
    
        'providers' => [
            'users' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => App\Models\User::class,
            ],
            'technicians' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => App\Models\Technician::class,
            ]
            // 'users' => [
            //     'driver' => 'database',
            //     'table' => 'users',
            // ],
        ],
    
    
        'passwords' => [
            'users' => [
                'provider' => 'users',
                'table' => 'password_resets',
                'expire' => 60,
                'throttle' => 60,
            ],
            'technicians' => [
                'provider' => 'technicians',
                'table' => 'password_resets',
                'expire' => 60,
                'throttle' => 60
            ]
    
        ],
    
        'password_timeout' => 10800,
    
    ];
```

In my controllers I am using this line to authenticate, which in return is giving me the error:

```php
    Auth::guard('mobile')->attempt(['email'=>'testmail@test.com',password=>'password']);
```

[image]

Comment: Share the error, what exactly Laravel says? Did you try `php artisan cache:clear`? or you can delete php files at `root-app/bootstrap/cache/*.php`

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin `InvalidArgumentException
Auth guard [mobile] is not defined.` , this is the error I am getting

Comment: Did you extend Authenticatable in Technician model?
`use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class Technician extends Authenticatable 
{`

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of error. I was using phpstorm to automatically upload files through ftp to the server. So, I accidentally had config folder excluded from the list of folders being synced. so my auth.php was never actually updtating.
Otherwise code is fine